Compensating IMU orientation
I have an IMU sensor giving me a normalized quaternion for its orientation. However this quaternion does not match the coordinate system that I want to use. For example, the roll and the yaw axis are swapped.
Negating or swapping the x, y and z components of my quaternion is not a suitable solution as I need to compensate for any orientation of my IMU, not only 90° rotations about axis.
How can I do this ? For now I have been using this code:
Quaternion getQuaternionFromEuler(float yaw, float pitch, float roll) {

    float yawRad = yaw * DEG_TO_RAD;
    float pitchRad = pitch * DEG_TO_RAD;
    float rollRad = roll * DEG_TO_RAD;


    float cy = cos(yawRad * 0.5);
    float sy = sin(yawRad * 0.5);
    float cp = cos(pitchRad * 0.5);
    float sp = sin(pitchRad * 0.5);
    float cr = cos(rollRad * 0.5);
    float sr = sin(rollRad * 0.5);

    Quaternion q_yaw = {cy, 0, 0, sy};   // Yaw autour de Z
    Quaternion q_pitch = {cp, 0, sp, 0}; // Pitch autour de Y
    Quaternion q_roll = {cr, sr, 0, 0};  // Roll autour de X

    Quaternion q = quaternion_multiply(q_roll, quaternion_multiply(q_pitch, q_yaw));

    return q;
}

Quaternion quaternion_multiply(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2) {
  Quaternion result;
  result.w = q1.w * q2.w - q1.x * q2.x - q1.y * q2.y - q1.z * q2.z;
  result.x = q1.w * q2.x + q1.x * q2.w + q1.y * q2.z - q1.z * q2.y;
  result.y = q1.w * q2.y - q1.x * q2.z + q1.y * q2.w + q1.z * q2.x;
  result.z = q1.w * q2.z + q1.x * q2.y - q1.y * q2.x + q1.z * q2.w;
  return result;
}


Quaternion quaternion_conjugate(Quaternion q) {
  Quaternion result;
  result.w = q.w;
  result.x = -q.x;
  result.y = -q.y;
  result.z = -q.z;
  return result;
}

m_initialRotation = getQuaternionFromEuler(0, 90, 0); //Rotating frame 90° around the pitch axis. This should put the yaw axis (Z) upward and the roll axis (X) forward.

Quaternion rotated = quaternion_multiply(quaternion_multiply(quaternion_conjugate(m_initialRotation), imu_quaternion), m_initialRotation);

However this is not giving me the correct results. For example the pitch angle gets affected correctly by the above code (giving me -90° instead of 0° initially), however the yaw (Z) and roll (X) axis are still swapped. I tried everything from changing the order of quaternions multiplication, not mutliplying by the conjugate quaternion... All giving sometimes good results but showing limitations when using combined rotations. I'm starting to think that maybe I cannot solve this problem with quaternion multiplications and that I need first to swap signs of axis to have a good handedness... Which is just a supposition because I'm really confused with this.
Thank you for the help

Don't think that voodoo magic with monte carlo programing solve your task. You have 2 coordinate frames. CS1 of returned quaternion and CS2 is your goal.

You should recover what a CS transform describes your quaternion. From IMU CS to global CS or inversed.
You should recover your CS1 into CS2 transform.

Knowing this 2 transforms you can build correct transformation chain. Did you tried ChatGPT for precise advise ?

Thank you for your answer. However what you advise seems really theoritical to me. What is "CS" ? "1. You should recover what a CS transform describes your quaternion". Sorry, but what does that sentence even mean ? I appreciate the help, but as you can see in my code, I would like some practical or maths formula. I do understand the steps I need to perform, but now I need to apply it which is were things become hard. And I did use ChatGPT a lot. However, it gave me unstable outputs, changing its answers from time to time or when I ask more detail about some parts.

CS == coordinate system or coordinate frame. " I would like some practical or maths formula. "  it is possible if you describe all your transformation chain. Or someone have experience with exactly your system.

Don't recommend ChatGPT as a means to "get precise advice". It literally can't give that, it can only perform a very fancy form of autocomplete. It has no concept of "correctness". Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned
